# Install firmware on router without username or password

Tags: router

I have a TP-Link internet router model: TL-WR740N ver. 4.27. It was provided by my ISP so I do not have the username or password. The reset feature does not reset the username or password. Is there any way to physically install new firmware without needing the username or password?

Comment: If you don't have the capability to access the configuration page then it won't be possible to upload the firmware even if you had access to a USB-to-Serial converter and accessed it over SSH.

Comment: First always try the "default" username and password (in your case its "admin" and "admin). Since you said it was provided to you by your ISP, assuming your ISP allows you to tinker with it, you can call them up and ask them for it so you can configure it to your need. If that fails, then not much you can do (as per Ramhound's comment).

Comment: @Darius I have tried the default username and password, it did not work. My ISP will not provide me with the username and password.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you actually successfully reset the router to factory defaults? I am not aware of any cases where consumer grade products are supplied and the factory reset did not actually reset it to factory defaults...

Comment: @agtoever I turn on the router with no cables attached. Three lights come on (power, wifi and lock). I press and hold the reset button for 10 seconds then release the button. No lights turn off. There is no sign the router has reset.

Comment: In that case, your router did not reset correctly. Either you did not press hard enough or not far enough (do you use a bent paperclip?!). You should feel/hear a click. According to the [manual](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WR740N_741ND_User_Guide.pdf) the router should be on and after pressing the reset button and keeping the it pressed for around 5 sec. it should reboot. If it doesn't reboot, it isn't reset.

Comment: @agtoever Following the manual and holding the reset button for 5 seconds (I do hear a click) does not reset the router. Is there a way to reset by connecting two locations on the PCB.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll put my comments in an answer now, because it won't fit in a comment*

Also: if you *rent* the router from your ISP some or all of the things below might be in violation with the contact with your ISP(!)

---

First try to reset your router in the "normal" way as described in [the manual](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WR740N_741ND_User_Guide.pdf):

- Turn the router on.
- Press the reset button with a bent paperclip or other pointy object (you should hear/feel a click when pressing the reset button). Keep the button pressed for about 5 to 10 seconds.
- The router should reboot itself, after which the factory defaults are loaded.

If this doesn't work for some reason, you could try the following ([source](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/tp-link/tl-wr740n); not sure if this works with the standard firmware though):

- Unplug the router's power cord.
- Connect any router LAN port directly to your PC.
- Configure your PC with a static IP address: 192.168.1.2
- Plug the power on to the router. Wait until the "SYS" LED starts flashing repeatedly.
- Press the "QSS" button (on the front/back of the router) → the "SYS" LED will now start flashing at a faster rate.
- Login to the router by using telnet to connect to the IP address 192.168.1.1 → there will be an immediate unauthenticated login to a root shell.
- Type the command `firstboot`. This will reset the router to factory defaults.

I found some other methods [here](https://giannoug.gr/unbricking-a-tp-link-tl-wr841nd/).

Final rescue (**not tested; use at your own risk!**): what the reset button does is to just connect two soldering points. Open up your router, check the backside of the PCB and follow the reset procedure in the manual, except instead of pressing the reset button, connect the two soldering points at the backside of the reset button with a piece of wire.